# Book about a girl on a snow planet who programmed the robots she owns and turns out to be a princess

Tags: story-identification, books, robots

The book is about a girl on a snow planet. She boxes for funds and owns tiny robots that she coded herself. I believe she had a wristband that helped her code if I'm not mistaken?

A ship crashes on her planet near her house, which is away from all the other people. The robots help her work in the mines by her house. She ends up having to go on a trip with the boy in the ship.

She finds out she's a princess and that her kingdom is corrupt. The title had something to do with snow.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please see our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any other details you remember (such as when you read the book / when it may have been written).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Joan D. Vinge's  _The Snow Queen_ comes to mind, but it's pretty far from what you describe.

Answer (score 29):

[*Stitching Snow*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/16067008-stitching-snow) (2014) by R.C. Lewis features a young woman, Essie, using coding on her seven robots for the mine on a cold planet, and she fights (even in the opening scene) for money.

A ship crashes near her, and she helps the young man, Dane, and has to go on a trip by spaceship with him.

She knows she's a princess but it doesn't come out until late in the story.

Comment: Don't know if that's the right story, but I started reading it and it's certainly worth the time.

Comment: Is this a Snow White variant?  It sounds like it.

Comment: Got it in one.  It is.